# Scrapy spider_idle call to restart scrape

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrape setup in Scrapy that is targeting 1M unique urls in a numeric sequence.  For example:  http://www.foo.com/PIN=000000000001

I hold the PINs in a DB. Rather than load 1M PINs into memory and creating 1M start_urls, I'm using the start_requests() function to query the DB for 5000 PINs at a time.  After completing the 5000 unique URLs I want to restart the scrape and keep doing it until all 1M URLs are scraped.  In the scrapy user group they recommended I use the spider_idle function to keep restarting the scrape.  I have it setup correctly per the code below, but I cannot seem to find the right code to restart the scrape.  See below:

```
class Foo(Spider):
    name = 'foo'
    allowed_domains = ['foo.com']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        print 'idle function called' # this prints correctly so I know this function is getting called.
        self.start_requests() #this code does not restart the query

    def start_requests(self):
        data = self.coll.find({'status': 'unscraped'}).limit(5000)

        for row in data:
            pin = row['pin']
            url = 'http://foo.com/Pages/PIN-Results.aspx?PIN={}'.format(pin)
            yield Request(url, meta={'pin': pin})
```

What code do I need to restart the scrape?

Comment: How does your `start_requests()` method look like? Thanks.

Comment: I just revised the code to include the start_requests() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of restarting the spider, I would query the database for `unscraped` items until there is nothing left:

```
class Foo(Spider):
    name = 'foo'
    allowed_domains = ['foo.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        while True:
            data = self.coll.find({'status': 'unscraped'}).limit(5000)

            if not data:
                break

            for row in data:
                pin = row['pin']
                url = 'http://foo.com/Pages/PIN-Results.aspx?PIN={}'.format(pin)
                yield Request(url, meta={'pin': pin})
```

You would probably need to implement a real pagination over the collection with limits and offsets.

Comment: I was trying to avoid putting 1M URLs into start_requests in order to keep memory usage down.  Your solution will definitely work, but I'd really like to run 5000 at a time and continuously restart the scrape until all 1M rows are marked as 'scraped' in the DB.

Comment: @dfriestedt sure, this is what I'm trying to say here. Paginate over the unscraped items: get 5000, yield a request for every row, get another 5000, yield a request for every row etc.. this will keep your memory usage down.

Comment: @dfriestedt I guess you would need to use `skip()`, see [this example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/).

Comment: The problem is the scrape yields results much slower than mongo can insert rows into start_requests.  So, I page over 5000 rows inserting each into start_requests that will be done in 5 minutes.  The scrape of 1M rows will take 3 days to complete.  This will result in excess memory usage, but will take a few minutes to get there.  Right?

Comment: @dfriestedt yielding 1 million requests will take time, I agree :) But, I'm not sure how would restarting the spider help here? Btw, in reality, I would install multiple scrapyd services and distribute the crawling, see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls. You would need to figure out how to partition your data to the scrapyd instances.

Comment: @dfriestedt additionally, try increasing the [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) setting.

Comment: I don't want crash the target server, which is why I keep CONCURRENT_REQUESTS low and I don't want to distribute across multiple scrapyd instances.  I simply want to load 5000 URLs into start_requests, scrape the URLs and then start the process all over when the 5000 are done.  I could do it manually, but I know changing spider_idle can accomplish what I'm looking to do, hence the original question.  I really just need to understand how to restart the scrape once it goes idle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62416/discussion-between-dfriestedt-and-alecxe).